# How do I use a DV Camcorder as a Webcam?

Tags: webcam

I have a DV camcorder that works with webcamstudio, but I don't know how to get it to work as a the default webcam.

Answer (score 1):

As you state that the Camcorder does work with webcamstudio then this should be possible although it would take a bit of manipulation. These instructions may help if you wish to specify the camcorder to act as default for certain programmes (you'd need to change 'skype' to whatever programme you wished to use the camcorder:

[[SOLVED] Use a DV cam as a webcam - Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1712667)

> Install "dv4l" from the Ubuntu Software Center (on the "Applications" menu on your desktop)
>
> Edit your user groups so that you can use the video device. Open System-> Admin-> Users and Groups, Click advanced settings for your account, click user privelages tab, ensure there is a checkmark by the "Use Video device" option and hit "OK". Then click "Manage Groups", scroll to "Video", click "Properties" and ensure your user name is part of that group.
>
> Create an application launcher (right click desktop and select "Create Launcher". Type a name such as "Skype with DV/Cam" and for the command put:
>
> dv4lstart skype /dev/video0
>
> Restart your computer and double click your launcher. Make sure you select the new "webcam" in the Skype options.

Comment: Note: I had to install "gnome-system-tools" in order to modify the Users and Groups settings. This can be done from the Software Center.